# Can not run a simple example

Tags: android, retrofit

Here is my code. I have added

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
```

to dependencies to `build.gradle`.

I have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to manifest.

And here is a code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String API_URL = "https://api.github.com";

    public static class Contributor {
        public final String login;
        public final int contributions;

        public Contributor(String login, int contributions) {
            this.login = login;
            this.contributions = contributions;
        }
    }

    public interface GitHub {
        @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
        Call<List<Contributor>> contributors(
                @Path("owner") String owner,
                @Path("repo") String repo);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onAddClick(View view) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        GitHub github = retrofit.create(GitHub.class);

        try {
            Call<List<Contributor>> call = github.contributors("square", "retrofit");
            List<Contributor> contributors = call.execute().body();
            for (Contributor contributor : contributors) {
                System.out.println(contributor.login + " (" + contributor.contributions + ")");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

When I am running this code using debugger on the line

```
Call<List<Contributor>> call = github.contributors("square", "retrofit");
```

I get the message "Unfortunately, MyAppName has stopped". How can I fix it ?

**Updated:**

Here is my `logcat`:

```
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329] Throwing new exception 'length=215; index=630' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=215; index=630
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void com.example.demas.customwidget.MainActivity.onAddClick(android.view.View) (MainActivity.java:54)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(android.view.View) (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at boolean android.view.View.performClick() (View.java:5198)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.view.View$PerformClick.run() (View.java:21147)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:739)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:148)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-28 02:12:40.125 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329] 
03-28 02:12:40.178 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
03-28 02:12:40.178 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
03-28 02:12:40.178 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] 
03-28 02:12:40.178 31118-31118/com.example.demas.customwidget A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31118 (as.customwidget)
```

Comment: can you post your error logs?

Comment: can you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in your manifest and see what happens? also please post logcat.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal, I have updated the question

Comment: @gj_, I have done it and added logs to the question

Comment: This issue has been addressed here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1506 and https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1486

Comment: I ma using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha4`.  I can not use `2.0.0-alpha3`, beacuse Android Studio gives a messege: "Plugin is too old".

Comment: Then use `alpha3`.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal, Thanks. I can not use `2.0.0-alpha3`, beacuse it is `too old`, but I install Android Studi 1.5 with `gradle-1.5.0` and all works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the same problem disabling `Instant run` mode in Android Studio.

Here is the discussion https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1486 about the bug, another possible solution is upgrading version of gradle plugin.